# I have a 6000 character images. And i want to create an array of all images

Tags: matlab

i want to create a mat file. Through which i can train my neural network for OCR.  I have 6200 images of size 30*30 .How can i create an array of all images. size will be 6200*30*30 and then want to unroll image into 6200*900. plz help
currently m able to read the files but not able to process my operations

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have your images in some format in the current working folder, and all are of the same dimension.

Also, I assume you're interest in black and white images (otherwise you'll have to take into account the triple dimension of the RGB field).

If it is so, you can simply read them and store them in your array:

First create in some way a cell containing your filenames:

```
fileName = {'image1.png';'image2.png'};
```

Allocate space for your image matrix:

```
h=30; w=30;
imagesArray = zeros(length(fileName),h,w);
```

Sequentially read and store images in your empty matrix:

```
for n=1:length(fileName)
    imagesArray(n,:,:) = imread(fileName{n});
end
```

Finally you unroll:

```
unroll = reshape(imagesArray,length(fileName),h*w);
```

Comment: You could also find all `png` images in a folder using `dir('folder/*.png')`. This returns a struct, which contains some info on each file, including its name.

Answer (score 0):

The code will be something like:

```
for ii=1:6000
    data(ii,:,:)=imread('yourfilename_ii.png'); %//this only works if they are FOR SURE 30x30 all
end

% Now reshape!
data=reshape(data,[6000,30*30]);
```

Comment: yaa this works Mr. Biguri....can u suggest how i will do the same thing if i am having variable image size(i.e. one image with 20*20 and other 30*30)